# How does the photon interact with the changing spacetime (say when massive object appers nearby)? How does it know how to "bend"?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, gravity, quantum-electrodynamics, gravitational-lensing

How does the photon interact with the curved spacetime?

Say, we have the photon travelling through the universe.
Then it enters the region of gravitatonal lens (or a curved spacetime created by some moving massive object)
The massive object moves in, and it "brings" with it the curved spacetime, right? And this "distortion" spreads immediately and influences the trajectories of all the photons nearby.

So when an object moves in, the photon starts to take a different path following the spacetime curvature.

But HOW does the photon know this?

If we assume 2 things my question will become more clear:

- say that a massive object like a black whole was born instantly out of some other photons collided in this region (its possible in theory)
- the gravitational distortion it brought with it, bended the spacetime immediately (faster then light) AFAIK the "gravitational waves" are instant, FTL

Will the photon travelling nearby start to follow the (newely emerged) curvature immediately?

Anyway how does it know how to react to spacetime change?
There is NO physical interaction between the photon and the (newely born) massive object.
They do not exchange (virtual) particles like in electromagnetic interactions.

It just works. But how?

[image: massive object deforms spacetime]

Comment: Photons curve space-time since the stress-energy tensor of the electromagnetic field is non-zero. Thus, space and time were deformed before the black hole you describe was born. In fact, this is why there's a black hole in the second instance.

Comment: "And this "distortion" spreads immediately and influences the trajectories of all the photons nearby." No, definitely not, this is the point of relativity!!

Comment: "AFAIK the gravitational waves are instant, FTL." This part isn't true though, that's the whole point of gravitational waves, like EM waves, they take time to travel from source to detection point.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you can experiment at home to get some intuition about this.

Get hold of a steel measuring tape of the kind that you can buy in a hardware store. Bring out a length of a metre or two of tape. Notice that the tape is quite bendy, but nevertheless the two sides of it remain parallel and the distance marks along it do not get squeezed or stretched as the tape bends.

This tape can serve as a way of marking out a line along a surface, where the line is the kind called "geodesic" which does not swerve to the side as it goes. If you lay the tape on the floor the geodesic looks straight to us. But you can also lay the tape along other surfaces, such as the surface of a large sphere. As it wraps around the sphere it will follow a great circle.

Now here is the purpose of this illustration.

You can imagine such a "tape" but now laid out in spacetime rather than just space. And in particular you can imagine a tape whose direction in spacetime is such that movements along it are movements at the speed of light. Now a light beam finding itself moving along such a tape does not steer to left or right relative to the tape. It just goes straight ahead. But the tape itself has to follow the shape of spacetime. So the light does also. The light at any event does not "know" what spacetime is doing, except that it can "tell" there is a straight ahead direction relative to the preceding part of its worldline. That is the direction it follows next. Meanwhile the spacetime, warped by gravitation of a nearby massive body, results in such a path ending up traveling in a new direction overall, not because the path wandered to left or right, but because it was following a curved space, just like the tape measure which can find its way to a new direction without ever bending directly left or right relative to its own surface.